# Assign document from MongoDB query to variable in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm trying to assign a MongoDB document object to a Javascript variable running on a Node.js server. I'm having trouble understanding how to do this with the async behavior of the MongoDB driver on Node. In my main `app.js` file I have the following

```
// MongoDB
//-------------------------------------------------
var DOC = require('./test_mongodb.js');
console.log(typeof(DOC)); //<---------------- this fails
console.log('Works:', JSON.stringify(DOC)); //<------------this fails
```

The required file `test_mongodb.js` is as follows

```
const config = require('../config/mongodb.config.js'); // <--- This just pulls in the ip:port and database name...nothing special
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

var DOC = {};  // <------------------I want to store a document here

// Client
const mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://' + config.db.host;
console.log(config.db.host);

// Use connect method to connect to the server
mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Connected to mongoDB server");

    // Select database
    const db = client.db('DATA');

    // Get the documents collection
    var coll = db.collection('TEST');

    //We have a cursor now with our find criteria
    var cursor = coll.find({"name": "testing"});

    //Lets iterate on the result
    var count = 0;
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Fetched:', doc);
        if (count == 3) {
          //console.log(typeof(doc));
          //DOC = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc)) ;
          //console.log(typeof(DOC))
          //console.log('Inside:',DOC);
          DOC = doc; <----------------------just capture one doc
        }
        count = count + 1;
      }
    });
  }

  // Close connection when done
  client.close();

});
console.log(typeof(DOC));
console.log('Inside:',DOC);
module.exports = DOC;  // <-------------I want to export the variable here
```

The output of `console.log(typeof(DOC))` in `app.js` is undefined. Overall, I realize this is a problem with the async behavior, but I don't understand how to correct it. I've read that the solution is to use callback functions, but I don't fully grasp how this is done here with Mongo. In your solution, please give a detailed explanation of how the callbacks are physically working as this is my main confusion.

One other side question...is there a difference between cursor.each and cursor.forEach?

Comment: NOTE: The `count` stuff is purely for testing purposes. Mainly I just want to store a returned query to an object and return it. It could be a full query, doesn't matter. Point is, I can't get the export functionality to work.

Comment: console.log(cursor) once and check if it has data ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `module.exports` assignment is happening before the query is complete.

Your environment probably supports Promises, so you can return one here. Here's how your code should like:

`test_mongodb.js`

```
const config = require('../config/mongodb.config.js'); // <--- This just pulls in the ip:port and database name...nothing special
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

var DOC = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Client
    const mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    // Connection URL
    const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://' + config.db.host;
    console.log(config.db.host);

    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log("Connected to mongoDB server");

            // Select database
            const db = client.db('DATA');

            // Get the documents collection
            var coll = db.collection('TEST');

            //We have a cursor now with our find criteria
            var cursor = coll.find({
                "name": "testing"
            });

            //Lets iterate on the result
            var count = 0;
            cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Fetched:', doc);
                    if (count == 3) {
                        resolve(doc);
                    }
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            });
        }

        // Close connection when done
        client.close();
    });
})

module.exports = DOC;
```

Then wait for the promise to resolve in the parent.

`app.js`

```
require('./test_mongodb.js').then(function(DOC) {
    console.log(DOC);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Would this require that I work with "DOC"  inside the function, where `console.log(DOC);` is written? In my original question I had `var DOC = require('./test_mongodb.js');` such that "DOC" is a variable defined within the scope of `app.js`. Is this just not possible with the async behavior? If I'm not mistaken, the solution you provide suggests "DOC" has a limited scope with respect to `app.js`? Again, I'm not use to async programming, so I'm just trying to clarify my understanding.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack the way I see it, the code is evaluated before the connection to the database is made, so your variable is empty before that. The promise ensures that the database connection is established before you use `DOC`. Also, I don't know of any way to not use a callback with a promise, so there's no reliable way to give DOC to the global scope.